# Exact latex output for R summary of lm function in Rmarkdown pdf output

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

when we fit a linear model in like this,

```
x <- c(1.52, 1.6, 1.68, 1.75, 1.83)
y <- c(1.69, 1.74, 1.80, 1.93, 2.0)

fit <- lm(y ~ x)

summary(fit)
```

**Output**:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
        1         2         3         4         5 
 0.021416 -0.012387 -0.036190  0.020482  0.006679 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)  0.07633    0.19447   0.392  0.72093   
x            1.04754    0.11579   9.047  0.00285 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.0282 on 3 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9646,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9529 
F-statistic: 81.85 on 1 and 3 DF,  p-value: 0.002852
```

So, **what I want is a latex output of this "exact" table** for `Rmarkdown` pdf output file. I do not want such output that is produced that changes the table or does not include some information from this table. As I mean, exactly this same output but in `latex` output.

An example output would be like this image but for **single regrassion model** and also **contains all the information generated by  `summary(lm(y~x))`**

[image]

Note: I have used such libraties `sjPlot`, `stargazer`, `texreg` etc.
Currently I am using `R version 4.1.2`

Comment: So you want exactly the same output, but different. You want it to contain exactly the same information as `summary()`, but your example doesn't  (e.g.) contain the residuals which `summary()` has, and it does contain the `N` and the confidence intervals, which `summary()` doesn't have... and `stargazer` and `texreg` aren't good enough but you haven't said why?

Answer (score 2):

Using `echo=FALSE` produces what you want.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
x <- c(1.52, 1.6, 1.68, 1.75, 1.83)
y <- c(1.69, 1.74, 1.80, 1.93, 2.0)

fit <- lm(y ~ x)

summary(fit)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is not what I was looking for. I have edited the post so that the desired output should be more clear to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I am a big fan of `modelsummary` for making tables

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(modelsummary)
library(broom)
library(kableExtra)


 df = tibble(x = c(1.52, 1.6, 1.68, 1.75, 1.83),
             y = 1.69, 1.74, 1.80, 1.93, 2.0 )

fit <- lm(y ~ x , data = df)

tidy(fit)


modelsummary(fit,
             output = "kableExtra")
```

Which will produce a very basic `LaTeX` table. However, if you want to group them by dvs you can do something like this where you estimate your models, then use `broom`, and then

```
data("iris")

iris = iris %>% 
  mutate(versicolor = ifelse(Species == "versicolor", 1, 0), 
         virginica = ifelse(Species == "virginica", 1, 0))


## pass it to tidy for each model
tidy(model1)

modelsummary(list( model1 , model2, model3, 
                        model4,  model5, model6),
             output = "kableExtra")  %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1 , "Petal Length" = 3 , "Sepal Width" = 3))
```

Which should give you close to what you are looking for! You may need to look at more options in `kableExtra`.